# Fixing Angular memory leaks

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to optimise my Angular app and browsing several websites I found this practice too:

```
var cleanup = $scope.$on('someEvent', function() {  
    $scope.refresh();
});
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    cleanup();
});
```

Due to the fact I have several `$scope.$on` in my controllers I was wondering if it is correct to use it like this:

```
var first = $scope.$on('firstEvent', function() {  
    $scope.something1();
});
var second = $scope.$on('secondEvent', function() {  
    $scope.something2();
});
var third = $scope.$on('thirdEvent', function() {  
    $scope.something3();
});
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    first();
    second();
    third();
});
```

Is this good to implement and correct?

Comment: I think that destroying your $on (on $scope) is useless, as the controller (including $scope) is destroyed by angular. - please prove me wrong if it is ;-)

What i do in my projects is to destroy everything i'm listening/watching on $rootScope, because the $rootScope lives longer and may cause unexpected behaviour.

Comment: what do you expect any of this to do? Code logic shown  doesn't make any sense

Comment: @JohannesFerner So you use to destroy `$rootScope.$watch` too? No sense to destroy on `$scope` but `$rootScope`, isn't it?

Comment: @charlietfl I don't know what to expect, that's why I ask. I just found it here: http://www.dwmkerr.com/fixing-memory-leaks-in-angularjs-applications/ but I don't know if it will make any sense or not...

Comment: Not wanting to read a huge article. What specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @charlietfl The application handle very rich data and after a while of usage or in peak hours it get stuck... So I need to optimise it entirely

Comment: @Ayeye Brazo Yes, i use it (only) to destroy things on the ```$rootScope``` - especially ```$watch```ers
I also use https://gist.github.com/JohannesFerner/eee0841fd93abe48d33a to see how much watchers are on each state

EDIT: on directives you i also destroy eg. instances of 3rd party jQuery Plugins

Answer (score 0):

As [cited article](http://www.dwmkerr.com/fixing-memory-leaks-in-angularjs-applications/) says,

> **Angular should clean this up if you forget to**, but the advice is always do it yourself.

Putting safeguards around the expected framework behaviour is overcautious and can hardly be called a good practice.

While jQuery/jqLite (`element.on`) and third-party event listeners may lead to memory leaks and should be cleaned up on scope `$destroy` **or** [element `$destroy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#events) event.